# Conjunction Logic in Gitlab fails when supplied seemingly valid YAML

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set conditions in my `.gitlab.yml` file, following along with this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#supported-syntax), using point 7 (Conjunction / Disjunction), but the syntax that I'm using keeps being rejected by the gitlab yml validator.

What should happen is that if `VAR1` ends with 'thing' or `VAR2` is present (i.e. not null), then the job should be excluded from running.

Here's a snip from my YAML file:

```
build:
  except:
    variables: 
      - $VAR1 =~ /thing$/ || $VAR2
  script:
      - echo "Hello"
```

Whenever I try and validate this syntax I get the following message:

[image: Failing Validation]

I've also tried the following (unsuccessful) variants:

```
  - $VAR1 =~ /thing$/ || $VAR2 != null
  - $VAR1 =~ /thing$/ && $VAR2 != null (this was just testing an AND condition)
```

Whenever I list the conditions separately they pass validation.

What is wrong with my syntax? Is there a different way to achieve my desired validation? It feels like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation mentions:

> If you use multiple keys under only or except, they act as an AND. The logic is:
>
> > (any of refs) AND (any of variables) AND (any of changes) AND (if kubernetes is active)

This makes it seem like `any of variables` means an OR of each variable listed, so this should cover your requirements:

```
build:
  except:
    variables: 
      - $VAR1 =~ /thing$/ 
      - $VAR2 != null
```